Assign a task with Workflow SharePoint 2013 give error message
I have created a calendar with resources in SharePoint 2016 for employees to make a booking for board rooms.  The resources lists all the board rooms.
Once a booking is made and a board room is selected from the resources list, I want to assign a task to an employee to approve/reject the booking.  I've done this with SharePoint Designer.  But the workflow gives an error upon the 'assign task' step:
Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute. Details of last request: HTTP InternalServerError to http://xxx/xxx/_api/web/lists(guid'7a6bbcdc-5d7b-4fea-902a-9537832e8634')/Items(5) Correlation Id: 6509a3d4-f408-d93d-976b-022b1ef1309e Instance Id: eb80d77e-aaff-4ce0-b504-d79774f88ec8 The value for field 'Facilities' of type 'Facilities' cannot be serialized.
For some reason it will not proceed from this step forward and gets stuck here. It also does not send out the task via email.
What am I doing wrong or what does this error message mean?  Any help will be much appreciated.
